# How can create a graphic without any bars with Amchart4

Tags: amcharts4

we are using amchart with a project and we need to remove all bars and zoom/resize action 
Our final idea is to have exactly the same chart as this
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/advanced/charts/

with just right-click to save chart as image
is this possible?

I tried to set those variables

```
chart.seriesContainer.draggable = false;
chart.seriesContainer.resizable = false;
```

Comment: Do you mean the background grid in the chart area?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say if you have two axes x and y as below, its is possible to disable the grid for each axis like below

```
let dateXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
let valueYAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

dateXAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
valueYAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in next steps, but this don't solve completely my problem, I still have the zoom bar i need it be removed

Comment: after more tests, actually that proposed code doesn't solve my problem